# How Do You Import a Text File into Pycharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, text-files

My teacher gave me two text files (tweets.txt and keywords.txt) that I need to do an analysis on. I have downloaded these text files on my computer. How do I import these text files onto my pycharm project so that I can reference them in an input("enter the name of the file:") ? If it matters, I am working off of a macbook with the latest version of python. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you won't need to ask in Stack Overflow, just google it, anyways

```
dir = input("Directory ending with file")
f = open(dir+"txt", "r")
```

f is stored as a file
So I suppose you need a String then do

```
plain_text_file = f.read()
```

For good practises close the file later
`f.close()`
[Check this for more](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the text files in the same directory your python script is in. Then you can access the file by using the open function. For example:

```
f = open('tweets.txt','r')
contents = f.read()
f.close()
```

or:

```
with open('tweets.txt','r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to add text files in the same directory, this is why I asked. Sorry for the confusion, how do you do this on a macbook? Thanks

Comment: Oh, try copying the file and then pasting it into the desired directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can us numpy as follows

```
import numpy as np
txt_file = input("File directory/file.txt")
np.loadtxt(txt_file)
```

Look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-loadtxt-in-python/) for more details on this approach and a number of variations for using this function.